# MetalKit - How to fade pixels within a single render pass

Tags: swift, shader, draw, metal, fragment-shader

I have a Metal based rendering pipeline that renders a few overlapping squares. It loops over all the squares and draws them to the screen starting from the one furthest to the back and ending with the one closest to the front (painter's algorithm).

However, I need some squares in the middle to hide the contents of the squares underneath them slightly. I'm rendering all of the squares in the same render pass, so the fragment shader has read/sample access to the color that was put down by the square drawn before it. But a later square does not have write access to the color that was already drawn to the screen. At the same time, an earlier draw call does not have access to the pixels that will be drawn using future draw calls.

Is there a way for a later draw call to override a color that was placed using an earlier draw call (i.e. tile shading, multiple render passes, etc.)?

Comment: Sounds like you need a fixed-pipeline blending or programmable blending. You can either configure your pipelines to use fixed functions blending or in your shaders on `apple` family GPUs you can just use the `[[ color(N) ]]` as both input and output, so that you can blend the colors yourself.

Comment: That is what I'm hoping to do, but I think the ```[[color(n)]]``` syntax as an input to the fragment shader only returns the color that was just put down on the screen, correct? I would need the color of the next draw call

Comment: How would that work? It doesn't exist yet, because it's the next draw call. What you are looking for is order-independent transparency. Basically, you would store a fixed sized array of color samples and when that array fills up, you blend some or all of the colors in there together and continue rendering.